# Passing variable to the render in Rails controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing Rails 4 app with nested forms. I have form with nested fields. Creating works fine:

```
def create_medical_history
    @patient_id = params[:patient]
    @medical_history = MedicalHistory.new(medical_history_params)
    if @medical_history.save
      redirect_to patient_path(@patient_id)
    else
      render 'new_medical_history'
    end
end
```

The problem is in else condition. Firstly In my form I have `@patient` variable defined, so when I `render new_medical_history` @patient variable becomes nil.

I need to pass it back again. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you just make a global variable to save the value before the render happens?

Comment: You want to get `@patient` again in a new request: i.e. `@patient = Patient.find(@patient_id)`? Make sure that the user viewing this is allowed to see this (i.e. with CanCan or Pundit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define @patient again, in preparation for the render.

So for example:

```
else
  @patient = Patient.find_by id: @patient_id
  render 'new_medical_history'
end
```

or whatever you need to get patient assigned again.